# Why is it called a 9-8 suspension instead of 2-1 suspension?

Tags: theory, nonchord-tones

I know that usually suspensions are referred to by simple intervals, and this is the case with almost all suspensions (4-3, 7-6, 2-3, etc). However, we call it 9-8 suspension instead of 2-1 suspension. Is there a reason for this, either practically or historically?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is rooted firmly in the practice of basso continuo, where the figures 2 and 9 had different harmonic implications. The basic idea is that, when a ninth is indicated, the bass is one of the chord tones, and the ninth is a dissonant suspension. But when a second is indicated, it is the bass note that is the dissonant suspension which must resolve downward by step (e.g., what we might call a third inversion seventh chord).

As a typical example, consider Francesco Gasparini's early 18th century continuo manual *L'Armonico Pratico al Cimbalo* ("The Practical Harmonist At the Harpsichord").

In chapter VII on dissonances and resolutions, he says (square brackets are my clarification):

> The second may be considered the same as the ninth, since the ninth is
>   the compound of the second, and because ordinarily one indicates a
>   second [in the bass] and the interval [played] will be a ninth. There
>   is, however, a notable difference between the two, since the second
>   does not derive from, but proceeds to a tie, that is to say, when the
>   bass is tied or syncopated. In this case, the second does not resolve,
>   as do the other dissonances, but instead the bass itself resolves
>   stepwise downward.

Here's a link to the page in question (p. 49), which contains a musical example that better illustrates his meaning:
https://archive.org/details/practicalharmoni002034mbp/page/n65

A few pages later (p. 51), he even points out that, if, for some reason, there were an actual 2-1 suspension and resolution, it is recommended to play it an octave higher (as a 9-8), because the resolution to an already-held note doesn't work on keyboard:

> If a second is found tied like a ninth, which resolves to the octave,
>   the second should be resolved to a unison. But since the keyboard is
>   not adapted to it, such a resolution would not be heard. For this
>   reason, when such ties are needed (which is rare in harmonic
>   composition) once can use a ninth instead, which is more distinctly
>   resolved to an octave -- as will be seen in the proper place.

Finally, we can compare against his treatment of ninths, where he makes the same distinction, but, I think, explains it more clearly. (p. 60)
https://archive.org/details/practicalharmoni002034mbp/page/n77

> Even though the ninth is the equivalent of the second, being a
>   compound second, still it is treated differently. It is never used
>   without a tie: in contrast to the second, which occurs over a tie in
>   the lower part (the bass), the ninth itself is tied in the upper part
>   in order to be resolved to the octave.

Once again, there is an example to demonstrate his meaning.

---

Since this answer received some additional attention recently, and has an incoming bounty, I decided to create a little example of my own to compare the difference between 2nds and 9ths. At each of the first three barlines, there is a C in the bass voice against a D in the soprano voice.

At the first and third barlines, the bass is suspended while the soprano moves to the D, so the interval is considered a 2nd and the bass must resolve downward by step while soprano voice holds the D. However, at the second barline, the soprano's D is suspended while the bass moves, which means the interval is a 9th, and the soprano must resolve down stepwise.

- *(Also, notice the difference in the chords that accompany the 2nd's, and the resulting harmonic implications: the 5/4/2 implies the bass is a suspended fourth, while the 6/#4/2 implies a 3rd inversion dominant 7th chord, and creates a modulation to the dominant, which I reinforce with a cadence)*

[image]